# Can we prove that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $T_4$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the subspace (Euclidean) Topology is a $T_4$ space.

So my thoughts go as follows: We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subspace, so if we can show that $\mathbb{R}$ is metrizable (I think with the Euclidean topology) then we get that $\mathbb{Q}$ is $T_4$.

If my thought process is correct, do I still need to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is metrizable w.r.t the Euclidean topology.

Comment: A subspace $Y$ of a $T_4$-space $X$ is $T_4$ if $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

Comment: A metric space is always $T_4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reacted the same way (not always a good sign).  Of course we know that $\mathbb R $ is metrizable. It has a well-known metric, which induces the standard topology. Hence so is the subspace $\Bbb Q$.  And we can be on our way.

That the metric, the standard distance function $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ induces the standard topology ought to be pretty clear, since an open interval $(a,b)$ is precisely an open ball $B(a+\dfrac{b-a}2,\dfrac{b-a}2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Q$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ which is metrisable so $\Bbb Q$ is metrisable.

All metrisable spaces are $T_4$, so $\Bbb Q$ is too. QED

Alternatively: all metric spaces are $T_5$ (hereditarily normal) so $\Bbb Q$, being a subspace, is too.